# Is it possible to allocate slices of disk to a KVM storage pool?

Tags: rhel, kvm, virt-manager, virsh

When using `virt-manager` to create a storage pool it does not give the option to set the size. Instead, it assumes that an entire partition is available to the pool. I would expect this to cause problems if more than one pool is defined and configured to reside on the same filesystem even if in different directories.

With 'virsh' there is the option to directly edit the XML for the pool. However, when I did this all of the `capacity`, `allocation`, and `available` values went to zero and `virt-manager` still displayed the entire filesystem size.

Is it possible to slice out segments of a filesystem as a storage pool or does each pool need to reside on its own filesystem if I want to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disk slices, as you call them, are typically realised in Linux using LVM. So what you need is to use an LVM based pool, where disk images will be LVs - disk slices at the block level.